# Spring Integration XML: getting value from message header

Tags: spring-integration

A Message object is passed to a service activator bean definition in XML as follows:

```
<int:service-activator>
  <bean class="BatchWriter"
    p:headerValue="...">
  </bean>
</int:service-activator>
```

Within XML, what is the correct syntax to use to get a specific header value from the message and pass it as a parameter to the service activator bean?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This should be enough for you:

```
class BatchWriter {

    MyPojo2 service(MyPojo1 payload, @Header("foo") Object foo) {
        ....
    }

}
```

So, the `@Header` does the stuff.

Cheers

Comment: Or you can define your `BatchWriter` as a top level bean and use `expression="@batchWriter.foo(payload, headers['foo'])".